# Avoid argument duplication passed through (...)

Tags: r

I have a function

```
somefun <- function(someparameters , ...) { plot(stuff, ...)}
```

Now I would like to provide some defaults for plot in the case that the user hasn't specified those arguments. (i.e. `xlab=""`).

How do I provide a set of default plot options but still allow the user to override those arguments? Since if the same argument is inputted twice, R will throw the error: formal argument matched by multiple actual arguments.

I am aware that I can pass on all these options through my function

```
somefun <- function(someparameters, main, xlab, ylab, xlim....)
```

but I would rather not do that.

Is there some easy neat solution to achieve this?

Comment: What is your objection to `somefun <- function(someparamenters, main, xlab="", ...) {plot(stuff, xlab, ...)} `?  I would have thought that is exactly what you want.

Comment: It's not neat. seems unnecessary, and the parameters will show up in the documentation when I put this code in a package

Comment: I submit that your users will want these parameters in the documentation, and so Henry's suggestion is preferred.

Comment: I would prefer to keep the plot looking the way it is. This is just a precaution so that my function won't throw an error, and if someone REALLY wants to modify something. It is not my intention to provide flexible arguments users can customize to their hearts content.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try `modifyList` used as follows:

```
f <- function(x, ...) {
    defaults <- list(xlab = "x", ylab = "y")
    args <- modifyList(defaults, list(x = x, ...))
    do.call("plot", args)
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. however how do i get the list to act as a parameter now? i.e. `plot(1,2, args) ` definitely will not work in this case

Comment: @Ellipsis That's the magic of `do.call` : it takes the arguments as a list. See also `?do.call`.  +1 for `modifyList`, didn't know that one. I'd have worked with the `match.call()` result, which is far from as neat as this.

Comment: @Ellipsis, I have modified it to give a `plot` example.

Comment: Note that this will break lazy evaluation.  That may or may not be important for your function.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider using the list2 function from rlang

```
my_dots <- rlang::list2(...)
```

This will return a list of the arguments passed to somefun. You can then insert your own logic to determine if it exists and what to do next.

```
if( has_name(my_dots, "xlab") ){
  xlab <- my_dots$xlab
} else {
  xlab <- ""
}
```